# PMF when given chance of success

Tags: probability

I'm stuck on the following question and want to know what it is that I'm doing wrong.

```
Consider a communication source that transmits packets.
After each transmission, the receiver sends a signal indicating if the transmission was successful or unsuccessful.
If a transmission is unsuccessful, the packet is resent.
Assume that the results of successive transmissions are independent of each other and that the probability of a transmission being successful is p=0.9.
Let X be the number of times a packet is transmitted.
a. Determine the PMF of the random variable X = number of times a packet is transmitted.
b. Find the expected number of times a packet is transmitted.
c. Find P(x=4)
```

I feel like for part a the general formula would be the following.

a.
$\frac {.9^x}{x} $ for x > 0

0 otherwise

b. Isn't part b asking the same as part a pretty much? Here is where I'm getting confused since it seems to me as though a packet has a chance of 1 - $\frac {.9^x}{x} $ to fail.

c.
$P(x=4) = \frac {.9^4}{4} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of times the packet is sent. Then $X=n$ if there were $n-1$ consecutive unsuccessful attempts, followed by success. Thus for $n\ge 1$, we have
$$\Pr(X=n)=(0.1)^{n-1}(0.9).$$
The random variable $X$ has **geometric** distribution.

It is a standard fact about the geometric distribution that $E(X)=\frac{1}{p}$, where $p$ is the probability of "success." In our case, $E(X)=\frac{1}{0.9}$.

**Remark:** The expectation of a geometric random variable has been repeatedly computed on MSE. We can do it by summing an infinite series, or by a conditional expectation argument. Let $e$ be the expectation. With probability $0.9$, the first trial results in success, in which case $E(X)=1$. With probability $0.1$, the first result is a failure, in which case the expectation is $1+e$. For we have used up a toss to no effect, and the expected number of *additional* tosses is $e$. Thus
$$e=(0.9)(1)+(0.1)(1+e).$$
Solve this linear equation for $e$.

Comment: I'm slightly confused at how you're getting to e for the additional losses. I understand all the way up to there.

Comment: I will give a slightly different derivation. Send the first packet. Cost is $1$. With probability $0.9$, it's all over, no resending necessary. With probability $0.1$, resending is necessary. In that case, the expected number of **additional** sends is $e$. Thus $e=1+(0.1)e$.