# Expected number of coin flips

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume that when you flip a coin, the probability of getting heads is $1-\alpha$. If you need to flip the coin $N$ times before getting heads, then one can write the expected value of $N$ like so:

$$
E[N] = \underbrace{1}_{1st\ coin\ flip} + \underbrace{\alpha}_{prob.\ it\ fails}\cdot \underbrace{E[N]}_{expected\ \#\ of\ further\ flips}
$$

I was presented the above equation in a lecture, but I cannot derive it myself. Can someone shed some light for me and tell me how this is derived?

Comment: This has been discussed repeatedly on MSE, most recently [today.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728043/pmf-when-given-chance-of-success) The notation there is not the same as yours, but perhaps it will be helpful. If you need further help, I can discuss it in comments. Am reluctant to give an answer, since the question is very much a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as renewal argument. The logic behind it is to condition on the result of the first toss.

***Intuitively*** at the first toss two things can happen

1. You can toss heads with probability $1-α$ and in that case you are done. But you have done 1 step.
2. You can toss tails with probability $α$ and in that case you start anew with the second toss. But again you have done 1 step. Counting this 1 step, it is as if you start tottaly from the beginning with the second step.

Thus $$E[N]=(1-α)\cdot1+α(1+Ε[Ν])=1-α+α+α\cdotΕ[Ν]=1+α\cdotΕ[Ν]$$

---

***Formally*** denote with $X$ the result of the first step, with $X \in \{T,H\}$ and $P(X=T)=α$ and $P(X=H)=1-α$. Then by the law of total expectation: $$E[N]=E_X\left[E_{N|X}[N|X]\right] \tag1$$ where

1. $E[N|X=H]=1$ and
2. $E[N|X=T]=1+E[N]$

Thus, substituting in (1) we find that $$\begin{align*}E[N]&=E_X\left[E_{N|X}[N|X]\right]=P(X=H)E[N|X=H]+P(X=T)E[N|X=T]=\\&=(1-α)\cdot1+α\cdot(1+E[N])=1+α\cdot E[N]\end{align*}$$ which yields the same result.